# Sickly snake plant

Tags: houseplants

Snake plants (Sansevieria trifasciata) are supposedly really easy to care for, but mine is perpetually sickly. I have had it for about 8 years and it just has gradually declined, the leaves getting thinner and drooping over time. Some of the older leaves died and dropped off. Some new leafs have grown, but they are very small and sickly. The plant is a shadow of its former self. I have tried watering a lot, watering a little, everything. Eight years of experimentation and no matter what I try, the thing just gets worse every year. The soil is well drained. Light is indirect.

Any advice for what I might do?

Comment: Can you add a photograph please?

Comment: More light, less water.  These plants grow outside not far from the equator in Africa.  Yes, they are sold as low light but if you want them to do well give them high light

Comment: What did you use for soil?  Garden soil or potting soil?  What have you used for fertilizer?  That is as important as light or water...no fertilizer?  Plant is unable to make its own food.  Period.  No food plant dies.  Sticky means insects that are attracted to weak plants.  Please a few bits more of info and pictures!  Thanks!

Comment: OOOppps.  You said sickly not sticky.  Oh well, let us know more detail about light, water, soil and fertilizer...okay?